# Throttling requests to a API in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, throttling

I'm doing a huge change in a remote API, which envolves the following workflow:

```
FETCH items (retrieves 100 items)
   FOR item in items:
        DETAILS = FETCH item/details
        validate_details(DETAILS)
        if valid:
            RUN POST/PUT
```

So in this case, I need to do a lot of requests, which some of them rely on some validations.

My big question here is about how I throttle the requests here? Is there a library in Python to handle with this?

If not, I was thinking in create a Thread, which will consume a queue of requests and, based on the status code (429, 500), increase the parallelism of it.

Comment: By "throttle", do you mean that you want to retry requests that get rate-limited?

Comment: By throttle, I mean to run the maximum requests in parallel as possible

Comment: @RamonMedeiros are these calls required to be Sync or Async?